# Passing multiple input files to a Perl script through command line

Tags: perl, command-line, getopt

I am using Getopt function to open 2 separate files with different extensions (`.txt` and `.aspx`) in my Perl script by passing single command line argument.

Now, there are many such files of both kinds located in separate folders under the same directory.  (Many `.txt`'s in folder `text`. Same number of `.aspx`'s in folder `excel`. Folders `text` and `excel` are under same directory `/pkv/kbv/skv/`).

I need to open these files one pair at a time and process them. Then repeat same for remaining pairs (any number). Can I do this by passing command line arguments for the "directory" and "files list"?

```
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);

GetOptions('in=s') or die;

$txt = $opt_in . ".txt";

$aspx = $opt_in . ".tab" . ".aspx";

open (TXT, "< $txt") || die;

...

close(TXT)

open (ASPX, "< $aspx") || die;

...

close(ASPX)
```

Comment: Could you please add an example to your question? It should include a sample directory structure, an example of how you want to call the script, and what the script should do with the arguments.

Comment: Also, the name of the language is "Perl", not "PERL".

Comment: I am passing the string through command line to open both these files. Then I am writing out one file in my script. Now, for all the pairs, I want to loop through my code and output one file.

Comment: I've added markup for extensions and directory names, along with code markup and other cleanup.  I assumed that "text" and "excel" were directory names, is that correct?  Please try to format your questions  a little better, so they are easier to read. it makes a difference.

Comment: Still missing an n example of how you want to call the script

Comment: Sorry for the poor formatting. First time using this platform.

Comment: I am calling the script by providing the script name and argument. For Ex: myscriptname -in resource.  I am wondering if I can open both files in my script from the command line. Note: There may be 1000's of each files and I want to open them one pair at a time. Will I have to provide a list of these files as an argument at command line?

Comment: What do you mean by "_open both files...from the command line_"? Strings entered at the command line are merely handed to the script. For example, you can pass the name of the directory which contains `text/` and `excel/` directories. Then, once the script has that name, it can "read" those subdirectories to get a list of files in them.  Then it can go (loop) over the list, where in each iteration it opens one file out of each of the directories and does what it needs to do with them. These are very basic things and I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Exactly, I will pass a string on command line which will have the directory names. My script will open files at these locations in every iteration of the loop.

Comment: Well, great :)  You'll find [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) (or rather [File::Glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Glob.html)) or [readdir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) useful to assemble the filelists. Now go do that and if there are problems with it post a question.